# Error 0x80070057 calling VertexShader for Direct3d11

Tags: directx-11, sharpdx, direct3d11

My Windows 8.1 system has Directx11 installed but my video card is Directx 9. I'm trying to use SharpDX libaries and getting an 'parameter is incorrect' error new'ing up a VertexShader object.

Here is what I've tried

1. Running Directx 9 and using those libraries instead. Microsoft doesn't allow download of Directx 9 libraries from their web site now.
2. Running using software emulation. This is early stage development so I'm ok with that software emulation at this stage. This attempt failed with another error.

The call is this. d3dDevice and vertexShaderByteCode are non-null

```
     new D3D11.VertexShader(d3dDevice, vertexShaderByteCode);
```

Question 0. Is there a way to identify what parameter it doesn't like? I'm using tutorial code which theoretically worked.

Question 1. Is the error coming from the video card?

Question 2. Is this a known issue?

thanks,

john

Answer (score 1):

If you enable the Direct3D Debug Layer you should get more information on why the call failed.

What is the name of your video card? What [Direct3D hardware feature level](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels/) is your video card? 9.1, 9.2, 9.3? You can check by running `dxcapsviewer` from a Visual Studio Command Prompt. DirectX 11 can support 9.1 - 12.1 feature levels so it's quite likely at least some set of features will work on your hardware.

Comment: Thank you. I've got 2 NVIDIA quadro 440's. They support 9.  They aren't gaming cards per se  but I'm only trying to get the software up and running. How do I enable the Debug Layer?

Comment: That should probably support Feature Level 9.3, but you should check that. For C++ instructions on the debug layer, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj200584.aspx).  For SharpDX, you'd use ``SharpDX.Direct3D11.DeviceCreationFlags.Debug``.

Comment: I'm not clear on how the debugging layer works. Is it supposed to generate stuff into the output window for Visual Studio? I don't see anything helpful there other than the fact that there was an exception. I think I'm missing the big picture on how its used

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I was using sample code for DirectX 11 and the version of the pixel and vertex shader was incompatible with the DirectX 9 card that I had. In the call to compile the shader the version of the pixel shader was ps_5_0, I needed ps_4_0_level_9_1, the version of vertex shader was vs_5_0 and I needed vs__4_0_level_9_1. The 'invalid argument' was the compiled shader code.